# How can I know the intents needed to open system activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have the need to open android's default screen settings, and previously I wanted to open android's default alarm configuration activity, in the future I'm thinking I would want to open GPS settings.

How can I get the information needed to start this activities? 
Where can I found the documentation about this?
What's the process for getting this information without googling for the specific activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list of Actions in the documentation listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html).

You can launch any of the sub activities in the settings app using something like:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Common Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html) listing in the documentation.

It's a pretty comprehensive listing of the actions, URI formats and MIME types for building Intents for the standard Android applications.